# Complex convolution in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, complex-numbers

I'm trying to run a simple convolution but with complex numbers:

```
r = np.random.random([1,10,10,10])
i = np.random.random([1,10,10,10])
x = tf.complex(r,i)

conv_layer = tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=x,
            filters=10,
            kernel_size=[3,3],
            kernel_initializer=utils.truncated_normal_complex(),
            activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType complex128 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32
```

Does anyone know how to implement such a convolution in Tensorflow?

Will I need to implement a custom op, or is there some better option here?

Frustratingly, complex matrix multiplication is possible, e.g. the following runs fine:

```
def r():
    return np.random.random([10,10])
A = tf.complex(r(),r())
B = tf.complex(r(),r())
C = tf.multiply(A,B)
sess.run(C)
```

So there's no real reason convolution shouldn't work, I would think (as convolution is essentially just matrix multiplication).

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Tensrflow are you using? When I use TF 1.0.1, the same problem exists.

Comment: Traced this to an issue on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2255 ; While the issue is closed it wasn't clear to me how to use complex numbers in a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but for anyone who still is interested: applying convolutions to complex valued data is not as straightforward as your usual data types, like float32. There are studies that investigat different network structures for this purpose (for example see this [link](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SkeRTsAcYm) for "Deep Complex U-Net"). There are implementations of these structures in [pytorch](https://github.com/litcoderr/ComplexCNN) and [tensorflow](https://github.com/JesperDramsch/keras-complex).

Answer (score 0):

All complex-valued features are split into either Cartesian (real, imaginary) or polar (modulus, angle) representations.  Nobody is really trying to use a single feature that is purely complex; I would love to be proven wrong!