# tensorflow CNN with complex features and labels?

Tags: tensorflow, complex-numbers

I recently found a paper where they used a CNN with complex 2D-feature-maps as an input. However, there Network also outputs a complex output vector. They used Keras with tensorflow backend.

Here is the link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04479.pdf

I asked myself if it is possible to build complex Deep Neural Networks like CNNs with tensorflow. As far as i know it is not possible. Did i missed something?

There are other related questions which adresses the same problem with no answer: [Complex convolution in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577458/complex-convolution-in-tensorflow)

when building a realy senseless model with real number in and output all works correct:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random, empty

n = 10 
feature_vec_real = random.rand(1,n)
X_real = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,feature_vec_real.shape)

def model(x):    
    out = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=x,
            units=2
            )    
    return out

model_output = model(X_real)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

output = sess.run(model_output,feed_dict={X_real:feature_vec_real})
```

but when using complex inputs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import random, empty

n = 10 
feature_vec_complex = empty(shape=(1,n),dtype=complex)
feature_vec_complex.real = random.rand(1,n)
feature_vec_complex.imag = random.rand(1,n)

X_complex = tf.placeholder(tf.complex128,feature_vec_complex.shape)

def complex_model(x):

    out = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=x,
            units=2
            )    
    return out

model_output = complex_model(X_complex)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

output = sess.run(model_output,feed_dict={X_complex:feature_vec_complex})
```

i get the following error: 
ValueError: An initializer for variable dense_7/kernel of  is required

So what is the correct way to initialize the weights of the dense kernel when having complex inputs?

I know there is the possibility to handle complex numbers as two different layers in the network. But this is not what i want.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user9290285 there was finally an answer on the other post, just FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64780555/12763497